# How to run specific test files in maven build using command line

Tags: eclipse, maven, build

I'm new to testing.I'am working on a project which has many test files. Some of these test files have compilation errors. I want to run a only a single file (which does'nt have any error).I tried using ***

> mvn -Dtest=MyTest clean package

*** but i'am still getting Build failure due to compilation errors in other test files.This is because the above command only skips that particular test execution where as the build is failing in the compilation phase. so, is there a way to skip compilation of test files which has errors, explicitly or compiling and executing error free test files only.I have maven-war-plugin in my pom.xml file in eclipse.

Comment: the whole project has to compile before you can run a test, either comment out the code that fails to compile or change the file extensions to something like .javax

Comment: I want to execute only a single test file. I couldn't comment out the code as they are many errors.Is there a way to exclude compilation of specific test files?